# Появляются ошибки, если в bpm-схеме после таймера идёт service task или script task (Alfresco's Activiti 6)

Tags: alfresco

Вопрос по Alfresco's Activiti 6. Если в схеме ставлю после таймера (`intermediate timer catching event` или `boundary timer event`) стоит блок `service task` или `script task`, то сыпятся ошибки, и процесс дальше не идёт.
Если стоит блок `service task`, то такая ошибка возникает:

> couldn't instantiate <полное_имя_класса>

где <полное_имя_класса> - имя класса, прописанное у блока `service task` в свойстве `class`.

Если `script task` - то такая:

> Can't find scripting engine for 'groovy'

При этом класс для `service task` в `classpath` есть, и библиотека для движка `groovy` тоже подключена.
Самое интересное, что эти ошибки сыпятся не всегда, и в 1 из 5-10 случаев всё срабатывает. Закономерность не нашёл.

ЗЫ Пробовал работать с таймерами и `service task` и в своем рабочем проекте (с `REST` и `Spring Web Mvc`), и в простеньком тестовом приложение, написанном на `Swing`. Ошибки возникают и там, и там.

Если описывать подробно, то для решения данной проблемы были попробовано следующее:

- В тестовом приложении:

  - в директорию `src/main/java` помещён класс `WEB-INF.classes.<пакеты_класса>.<короткое_имя_класса>` (причём в
    файле самого класса в `package` было прописано `<пакеты_класса>`) - не
    помогло
  - в директорию `src/main/java` помещена директория `WEB-INF/classes/<пакеты_класса>` со скомпилированным классов внутри
    (причём в файле самого класса в `package` также было прописано
    <пакеты_класса>) - не помогло
- в рабочем проекте в директорию `src/main/java` добавлен класс `<пакеты_класса>. <короткое_имя_класса>` (причём в файле самого класса
  в `package` было прописано <пакеты_класса>) - не помогло

При этом в конечном архиве с приложением (`jar` или `war` класс находился в директории `WEB-INF/classes/<пакеты_класса>`). При этом в рабочем проекте в зависимостях (и, значит, в директории `WEB-INF/lib` или в директории `lib` сервера `Tomcat`) лежал джарник с данным классом, расположенным в нужном пакете, и это тоже не помогло.

PS Пример моего тестового определения процесса:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/processdef">
  <process id="MaxShulTest_v20" name="MaxShulTest" isExecutable="true">
    <documentation>test process</documentation>
    <startEvent id="startEvent1"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="Task1" name="Task1"></userTask>
    <userTask id="Task4" name="Task4"></userTask>
    <userTask id="Task2" name="Task2"></userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-FEBA8018-5838-4AF2-8AE5-DED45EF36229" sourceRef="Task1" targetRef="Task2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-A71A6EB8-293E-4EA7-A876-670C8E4ABF7C" sourceRef="Task2" targetRef="ExclusiveGateway1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-1691D37B-9B00-452F-B031-124B3845912B" sourceRef="Task4" targetRef="ExclusiveGateway1"></sequenceFlow>
    <endEvent id="endEvent1"></endEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-EAC37DEB-9666-407E-8EE0-27C11CEC4302" sourceRef="ExclusiveGateway1" targetRef="endEvent1"></sequenceFlow>
    <exclusiveGateway id="ExclusiveGateway1"></exclusiveGateway>
    <boundaryEvent id="boundary_timer1" attachedToRef="Task1" cancelActivity="true">
      <timerEventDefinition>
        <timeDuration>PT1M</timeDuration>
      </timerEventDefinition>
    </boundaryEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-88CC1D13-0907-44CC-ACAE-6E2FC01C8A3F" sourceRef="startEvent1" targetRef="service_task_1"></sequenceFlow>
    <serviceTask id="service_task_1" name="service_task_1" activiti:class="ru.maxlich.app.test.activiti.model.service.LogDelegateService"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-B9705ABC-78B3-460A-80ED-613EE3147491" sourceRef="service_task_2" targetRef="Task1"></sequenceFlow>
    <intermediateCatchEvent id="timer_1" name="timer_1">
      <timerEventDefinition>
        <timeDuration>PT3M</timeDuration>
      </timerEventDefinition>
    </intermediateCatchEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-49554231-BC08-4237-8B48-6D5484289319" sourceRef="service_task_1" targetRef="timer_1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-7C4E0E46-E680-45F2-847F-8C37FFB16C53" sourceRef="timer_1" targetRef="service_task_2"></sequenceFlow>
    <serviceTask id="service_task_2" name="service_task_2" activiti:class="ru.maxlich.app.test.activiti.model.service.LogDelegateService"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-727BA009-3FE2-48DE-B41E-693FCE3D2F53" sourceRef="boundary_timer1" targetRef="service_task_3"></sequenceFlow>
    <serviceTask id="service_task_3" name="service_task_3" activiti:class="ru.maxlich.app.test.activiti.model.service.LogDelegateService"></serviceTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-7F9D801A-5C8F-4623-987E-2E3FC936126E" sourceRef="service_task_3" targetRef="Task4"></sequenceFlow>
  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_MaxShulTest_v20">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="MaxShulTest_v20" id="BPMNPlane_MaxShulTest_v20">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="startEvent1" id="BPMNShape_startEvent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="30.0" width="30.0" x="30.0" y="185.943858356366"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="Task1" id="BPMNShape_Task1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="559.25" y="134.5"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="Task4" id="BPMNShape_Task4">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="855.0" y="286.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="Task2" id="BPMNShape_Task2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="783.25" y="135.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="endEvent1" id="BPMNShape_endEvent1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="28.0" width="28.0" x="1122.25" y="189.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="ExclusiveGateway1" id="BPMNShape_ExclusiveGateway1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="1019.5" y="183.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="boundary_timer1" id="BPMNShape_boundary_timer1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="31.0" width="31.0" x="608.0803504247281" y="199.943858356366"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="service_task_1" id="BPMNShape_service_task_1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="71.0" width="110.0" x="135.0" y="138.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="timer_1" id="BPMNShape_timer_1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="31.0" width="31.0" x="303.13336181640625" y="158.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="service_task_2" id="BPMNShape_service_task_2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="82.0" width="107.0" x="390.0" y="133.5"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="service_task_3" id="BPMNShape_service_task_3">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="82.0" width="107.0" x="630.0" y="285.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-727BA009-3FE2-48DE-B41E-693FCE3D2F53" id="BPMNEdge_sid-727BA009-3FE2-48DE-B41E-693FCE3D2F53">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="630.9660814288677" y="229.07107294829532"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="661.2786598187816" y="285.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-FEBA8018-5838-4AF2-8AE5-DED45EF36229" id="BPMNEdge_sid-FEBA8018-5838-4AF2-8AE5-DED45EF36229">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="659.25" y="174.61160714285714"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="783.25" y="174.88839285714286"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-B9705ABC-78B3-460A-80ED-613EE3147491" id="BPMNEdge_sid-B9705ABC-78B3-460A-80ED-613EE3147491">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="497.0" y="174.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="559.25" y="174.5"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-EAC37DEB-9666-407E-8EE0-27C11CEC4302" id="BPMNEdge_sid-EAC37DEB-9666-407E-8EE0-27C11CEC4302">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1059.5" y="203.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1122.25" y="203.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-A71A6EB8-293E-4EA7-A876-670C8E4ABF7C" id="BPMNEdge_sid-A71A6EB8-293E-4EA7-A876-670C8E4ABF7C">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="883.25" y="181.7795571220596"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1021.9182556711604" y="200.5817443288396"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-88CC1D13-0907-44CC-ACAE-6E2FC01C8A3F" id="BPMNEdge_sid-88CC1D13-0907-44CC-ACAE-6E2FC01C8A3F">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="59.73834151603846" y="198.15436210137352"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="135.0" y="183.90973937655264"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-49554231-BC08-4237-8B48-6D5484289319" id="BPMNEdge_sid-49554231-BC08-4237-8B48-6D5484289319">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="245.0" y="173.71295813578445"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="303.13348175202987" y="173.93804900670392"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-7C4E0E46-E680-45F2-847F-8C37FFB16C53" id="BPMNEdge_sid-7C4E0E46-E680-45F2-847F-8C37FFB16C53">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="335.13323251092316" y="174.0643254128607"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="390.0" y="174.28491016247852"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-7F9D801A-5C8F-4623-987E-2E3FC936126E" id="BPMNEdge_sid-7F9D801A-5C8F-4623-987E-2E3FC936126E">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="737.0" y="326.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="855.0" y="326.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sid-1691D37B-9B00-452F-B031-124B3845912B" id="BPMNEdge_sid-1691D37B-9B00-452F-B031-124B3845912B">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="948.8221673355974" y="286.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1029.1648250460405" y="212.6648250460405"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл причину ошибки. Параллельно был запущен Activiti Modeler, который использовал ту же базу. Я остановил это приложение, и всё начало срабатывать без ошибок.